# WPF event trigger not working

Tags: wpf, events, animation, button, triggers

I'm new in programming (changing area, leaving Design) and pretty interested in WPF.
So I'm studying and doing some codes.
In this one, I'm trying to make an "invisible" grid (the gridNovoCliente, opacity = 0) to show up at a button click event (opacity = 1), with all its elements.
I want the grid/elements invisible until the user clicks the button.

But it's not working.
I've been Googling it for 3 days before decided to post here.
I get the error 'Set property 'System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard.Target' threw an exception.' at the EventTrigger line.

There will be more buttons once I get this one working, so I created a style.
Thanks in advance! 
Here's the code.

```
<Grid>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource templateButton}" Name="novoCliente" Content="Novo&#xa;Cliente" Margin="20,41,0,598" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center">
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.Target="gridNovoCliente"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                         From="0"
                                         To="1"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>

    <Grid Height="705" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="131,12,0,0" Name="gridNovoCliente" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="859" Background="#FF6FAA6F" Opacity="0">
        <TextBox Height="70" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="270,250,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="358" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    <Canvas>
        <Button  Name="novoCliente" Content="Novo&#xa;Cliente"  Margin="20,41,0,598" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center">
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" >
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="gridNovoCliente"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                     From="0"
                                     To="1"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
               </EventTrigger.Actions> 

            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>

    <Grid Height="705" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="131,12,0,0" Name="gridNovoCliente" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="859" Background="#FF6FAA6F" Opacity="0">
        <TextBox Height="70" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="270,250,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="358" />
    </Grid>
    </Canvas>
```

It's very simple, please try above xaml, it's works for me. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Vibin! But now the error 'Set property 'System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard.Target' threw an exception.' is at the line BeginStoryboard :(

Comment: It worked at a new file, must be something else in my code. Thanks a lot =)

Comment: yaah , just checkout, best of luck.. :)

Comment: Newbie question: how do I do that? hehe